# It's possible to extend from mysqli in a new class and use it as an static?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

What I want to do is this:

```
class DB extends mysqli {
 ...
}

DB :: connect( ... );

DB :: query( "SELECT * FROM myDB" );

class AnotherClass {
  function helloWorld()
  {
     DB :: query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
  }
}

function functions()
{
    DB :: query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
}
```

The point of this question is to avoid the use of the 'global' keyword like:

```
global $mysqli;
$mysqli = new mysqli( ... );

class AnotherClass {
   function helloWorld()
   {
      global $mysqli;
      $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM IDontWantToUseGlobalKeyword" );
   }
}

function functions()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM IDontWantToUseGlobalKeyword" );
}
```

A solution for this is to declare the mysqli variable in the $_ENV array, but I don't want to use $_ENV to manage the MYSQLI, I want to use a static class like DB (Is that possible?)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There's no benefit to it!

Comment: Look the difference, the code is more readable

Comment: Can't you use the mysqli methods in procedural style ?

Comment: More readable than what?  It doesn't seem anymore readable for me.  Additionally, statics are considered bad practice in OOP, they're really just globals in disguise.  They'll make your code difficult to unit test properly and reduce the flexibility of any class that uses your DB class because they can't be isolated from the DB class.  You're getting lots of drawbacks for no real benefit.

Comment: @Double Your question is the right way if you're using mysql, BUT, I need to use mysqli to support transactions, and if you use mysqli procedural style, you will see that this style requires to use a $link in the call (mysqli_query( $link, $query )). Then you will need to use global $link, and again we will in the same problem to avoid global keyword. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After of all, I found a solution:

```
global $mysqli;
$mysqli = new mysqli( ... );

class DB  {
  public static function getConnection()
  {
     global $mysqli;
     return $mysqli;
  }
 ...
}



$mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM myDB" );

class AnotherClass {  
  function helloWorld()
  {
     $db = DB :: getConnection();
     $db->query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
  }
}

class DBAccess {
   public $db;
   function __construct()
   {
      $this->db = DB :: getConnection();
   }
}

class MultipleMethodDBSupport extends DBAccess {
   function __construct()
   {
       parent :: __construct();
   }

   function m1()
   {
      $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
   }

   function m2()
   {
      $this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
   }
}

function functions()
{
    $db = DB :: getConnection();
    $db->query( "SELECT * FROM withoutUsingGlobalKeyword" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This falls under the [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  With the example you provided it would be much better to jsut pass the class a mysql object.

```
Class DB {
    protected $mysqli;
    function __construct( Mysqli $mysqli ) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }
    function helloWorld() {
        $this->mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM IDontWantToUseGlobalKeyword" );
    }
}

$db = new DB( new mysqli(...) );
$db->helloWorld();
```

Your examples don't seem to require any inheritance.

Comment: function functions() {

    global $db;

    $db->helloWorld();

}

Comment: @CrisHongKongCRISHK wanting to do that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: class AnotherClass { function helloWorld2() { global $db; $db->helloWorld(); } }